# Tensorflow graph inside class - how to manage sessions and scopes

Tags: python, class, tensorflow

I am trying to build a generic tensorflow infrastructure wrapped inside a simple one layer NN class (see code below).

I will be creating many NNets so I was wondering what was the best way to manage the sessions and the variables.

Typically, I'd like to get tf.trainable_variables() for only one network, not all of them (in the "show" function) so that I can print the network I want.

I also have to pass the session variable "sess" to every function, so that the variables are not re-initialized. 
I think I am not doing everything properly... Can someone help ?

```
class oneLayerNN: 

"""
Implements a 1 hidden-layer neural network: y = W2 * ([W1 * x + b1]+) + b1
"""

def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self.initOp = tf.global_variables_initializer()

def show(self, sess):
    tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
    tvals = sess.run(tvars)
    for var, val in zip(tvars,tvals):
        print(var.name, val)
    print()

def initializeVariables(self, sess):
    sess.run(self.initOp)

def forwardPropagation(self, sess, x):
    labels = sess.run(self.yHat, feed_dict={self.x: x})
    return labels

def train(self, sess, dataset, epochs, batchSize, debug=False, verbose=False):
    dataset = dataset.batch(batchSize)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)
        while True:
            try:
                batch_x, batch_y = sess.run(next_element)
                _, c = sess.run([self.optimizer, self.loss], feed_dict={self.x: batch_x, self.y: batch_y})
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break

with tf.Session() as sess:
    network.initializeVariables(sess)
    network.show(sess)
```

Comment: You can do `sess=tf.Session()`, and make it a class attribute. You don't _have_ to do it using `with`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a matter of taste and of how you intend to use your objects.

If it is OK for you to limit your objects to deal with a single `tf.Session` (as in Keras — should cover basic needs and probably a bit beyond), then you could simply instantiate a single `tf.Session` via your preferred Singleton-like pattern (maybe just plain old functions like in Keras).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

However I still have issues with the scopes of variables. How can I do to define variables as part as my object? I want to be able to do something like:

```
vars = network.getTrainableVariables()
```

And that should return only the variables defined in that object (not like tf.trainable_variables())

I can't find one example of a clean declaration of variables within a scope when using multiple networks at the same time (the scope being the name of the network for example).

At the moment when I run the code multiple times, it creates variables W,b, then W_1,b_1, then W_2,b_2 etc...

Also, I would like network.initialize() to initialize only the variables defined within this graph, not all variables in every network...

A solution would be to declare variables for network within scope 'name' and then be able to reset_default_graph within this 'name' scope but I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `tf.keras.Model` to manage state. Take a look at the [subclassing section of the tf.keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#model_subclassing). There are training examples using `Model.fit` there, but you can also just call the object directly, and it will collect variables and losses for you in properties (`variables`, `trainable_variables`, `losses`, etc.).

Whatever you do, I'd separate the model definition (anything that manages `Variable` objects) from the training loop. And when defining the model, `Variable`s should be attributes of the model definition object and created once (not necessarily in `__init__`, but protected by an `if self.attribute is not None: self.attribute = tf.Variable(...)`).